# k8s: Get access to pods

Tags: kubernetes

I newbie question related with k8s. I've just installed a k3d cluster.

I've deployed an [this helm chart](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/stable/docker-registry):

```
$ helm install stable/docker-registry
```

It's been installed and pod is running correctly.

Nevertheless, I don't quite figure out how to get access to this just deployed service.

According to documentation, it's listening on 5000 port, and is using a `ClusterIP`. A service is also deployed.

```
$ kubectl get services                                                                                                                                    
NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes                   ClusterIP   10.43.0.1      <none>        443/TCP    42h
docker-registry-1580212517   ClusterIP   10.43.80.185   <none>        5000/TCP   19m
```

**EDIT**

I've been able to say to chard creates an ingress:

```
$ kubectl get ingresses.networking.k8s.io -n default                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
NAME                         HOSTS                 ADDRESS      PORTS   AGE
docker-registry-1580214408   chart-example.local   172.20.0.4   80      10m
```

Nevertheless, I'm still without being able tp push images to registry:

```
$ docker push 172.20.0.4/feedly:v1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
The push refers to repository [172.20.0.4/feedly]
Get https://172.20.0.4/v2/: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

Comment: Hi, what infrastructure do You run You cluster on? Also which k8s version?

Answer (score 0):

Since the service type is ClusterIP, you can't access the service from host system. You can run below command to access the service from your host system.

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/docker-registry-1580212517 5000:5000 &

curl <host IP/name>:5000
```

Comment: Is not another way to get access to it. I'd like to deploy the chart and straightforwardly get access to the deployed service...

Comment: You can change the service type to either NodePort or LoadBalancer ( Prefered if your setup is on cloud).

Comment: You can run "kubectl edit service/docker-registry-1580212517" and change the "type: ClusterIP" to "type:NodePort" on the manifest file.

Comment: I've been able to create an ingress. I've edited post with details.